# procedural language understanding - static vs dynamic scoping

Tags: scope, scoping, dynamic-scope

I am having trouble understanding the answer to a homework we got back. I believe I am getting confused on the concepts of functions being "nested", but maybe that is wrong. I am looking for some help in regards to following the assignment of dynamic and static scoping values from the following code.

```
x : integer -- global

procedure set_x(n : integer)
    x := n
end

procedure print_x
    write_integer(x)
end

procedure first
    set_x(1)
    print_x
end

procedure second
    x : integer
    set_x(2)
    print_x
end

// program starts here
set_x(0)
first()
print_x
second()
print_x

Static Scoping Output: 1122
Dynamic Scoping Output: 1121
```

My thoughts as I go through each one:

**Static:**

- Run `set_x(0)`, this makes a local variable due to the parameter of n, but since we set x to n without declaring x locally (int x =..) we then update the global x to 0.
- Run `first()`, which does `set_x(1)`, which following the same logic updates x to 1 globally. we then run `print_x` within first which prints the global x of 1.
- Run `print_x`, which just re-prints 1.
- Run `second()` we locally declare x and run `set_x(2)`, which goes updates 2 to n. (because of the `set`, not the `second` procedure, right? We then run its `print_x` procedure which prints the 2.
- Run `print_x` which again just dumps out the 2.
- Resulting in 1122

**Dynamic** (more confused on this one)

- Run `set_x(0)` which sets the x and global x to 0.
- Run `first()` we hit `set_x` again and update x to 1. We print 1.
- Run `print_x` We re-print 1.
- Run `second()` We locally make x, we run `set_x(2)`, and set global x to 2. We then print 2.
- Run `print_x` Finally we re-print again and here is where I guessed 2, but the answer should 1.
- My guess 1122, actual answer is 1121

I am confused on that last part of the dynamic and why it is a 1, and not a 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of hard to follow your reasoning in some places, because you don't say *which* `x` you think is being printed or updated, and that's pretty much the whole ball of wax.

The big thing to remember is that *static scoping* (also called *lexical scoping*) is fully determined at compile-time.  Where something is *defined* determines its static scope.

*Dynamic scoping* is of course the converse; it's determined at run-time.  Where something *executes* determines its dynamic scope.

So, take a look at the `set_x` procedure.  It has no local `x` of its own, and it's defined in the global scope, so under static scoping, it can only ever update the global `x`.  This is true no matter where it is called, *even within the `second` procedure*.

Under dynamic scoping, however, the `set_x` call within `second` updates the `x` which is local to `second`, leaving the global `x` unchanged.

Notice that the very last `print_x` call will always print the global `x`, regardless of the scoping rules (because the `print_x` procedure is defined in the global scope, and the call to `print_x` is executed in the global scope).  So the difference is that with static scoping, global `x` is 2 at the end of the program; but with dynamic scoping, global `x` is 1.

Comment: So the reason dynamic scoping has a 2, is because it is a local variable being printed at that point in time, and not the global variable x? (since a local x is defined in second). If this is true, is this x still being set to 2 within the set_x method, but since set_x is called from second, it is still setting the local x rather in second rather than the global?